# Need clarification about mapping objects to database, annotations, and one to many relationships

Tags: java, database, hibernate, annotations, persistence

Need some help understanding if I'm on the right track here and exactly what I need to do. Hope someone can chime in.

So I've got three tables, Job, Authorization, and Filter. Each Job must have one Authorization and one Filter. Of course, each Filter could be used by more than one job and the same goes for the Authorization. However, the Filters and Authorizations don't need to know what Jobs they are being used by.

So that is a one to many relationship on the part of the Filters and Authorizations I believe right? Or am I off track? How is this modeled in a database? I believe the Job table needs to have a foreign key field to the Filter and Authorization tables. Do the Filter and Authorization tables need foreign key fields themselves to Job?

Next, how do I model this in Java objects and then how do I set up the hibernate or java persistence annotations? I believe the Filter class looks like:

```
class Filter {

    @OnetoMany
    @JoinColumn(name="filterID")
    private Job job;
}
```

and the Authorization class basically the same and then how would the Job class look? The thing that's really throwing me is that the Filter and Authorization classes don't need any knowledge of what Job they're associated with so I don't see the need for them to actually hold references to Job objects. Only the Job class needs to hold references to the Filter and Authorization objects. So do I really need the above code?

I'm hoping someone can help clarify all this for me as I can't seem to wrap my head around it. Databases are not my strong suit. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, using a @OneToMany annotation is not very recommended in your situation. Maybe you may want the other side to own the relation.

Check this article out:
http://josian.wordpress.com/2006/09/09/hibernate-annotations-bidirectional-one-to-many/

So, to your question, no, you do not need the above code.

You need something like this:

```
class Job {

    @Id
    //stuff...


    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn (name="authorization_id", nullable = false, updatable = false, insertable = false)
    private Authorization authorization;

    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn (name="filter_id", nullable = false, updatable = false, insertable = false)
    private Filter filter;
}
```

and on your Filter

```
@Entity
@Table(name="filter")
class Filter {

      //some stuff, but no relation!
}
```

EDIT:
The @JoinColumn is just the name you want to appear in your Job table. By default, if you dont specify the join çolumn name, it is going to be {foreignTableName}_id. In the case of Authorizatrion, if you annotated it like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="foo")
class Authorization{
 @Id
 @column(name="auth_id")
 private Long authId;
}
```

the default join column generated for you in the Job table will be

`"foo_id"` and will reference the

`"auth_id"` field in the

`"foo"` table.

**TO your final comment:**

Actually you **don't need** to put foreign keys in the db. In the Job Entity, the

@ManyToOne annotation already ensures **the keys will be placed for you**. The

`@JoinColumn` specifies the names of the foreign key. For example, if you want your foreign key name in the Job table to Authorization to be called 'authorization_fk', you would use

> `@JoinColumn('authorization_fk')`

and this is how it is gonna be placed in your Job table.

Comment: That's what I was thinking. As I said, the Job needs to know about Filters and Authorizations but not the other way around so I was hoping I didn't need to put any code in the Filter or Authorization class. So ManyToOne is what I want? Thanks. I'm confused though by some other stuff I've seen. Does the authorization_id column in your above code refer to a column in the Authorization table or the Job table? And where are the foreign keys? Just in the job table?

Comment: The authorization_id is the name of the join column hibernate is going to create for you in your Job table.  You may not specify it and it is going to be created for you. This authorization_id field will have exactly the same value as the corresponding primary key in the Authorization object. I will continue my post further.

Comment: That is excellent, thank you! Just one last bit I'm not sure about, where do I need to put the foreign keys in the DB? I'm assuming I need to create an actual foreign key relationship in my DB, would that just be on the Job table?

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you should use `many-to-one` relationship, from `Job` to `Filter` and another one from `Job` to `Authorization`.

As stated in hibernate documentation (see [24.1. A note about collections](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/#example-parentchild-collections)), a `one-to-many` reference from `Filter` to `Job` will make the `Job` considered as part of the `Filter` entity, which is exactly the opposite of what you want. So, `Job` has to point `Filter`. Since many `Job`s may point the same `Filter`, it is a `many-to-one` relationship.

You'd write your `Job` class this way:

```
public class Job {

    ...

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="filter_fk")
    private Filter filter;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="authorization_fk")
    private Authorization authorization;

}
```

Comment: Very nice explanation, thank you. I do still have a bit of confusion so I'll ask you as well. Where is the filter_fk column referred to in your code above? Would that column be in the Filter table or the Job table? I'm unclear on that part and also where do I put the foreign keys? On the Job table right? So I'd create a column in the Job table that holds an ID and is a foreign key to the id of the Filter table? Am I understanding that correctly?

Comment: The columns are create in the `Job` table. You don't "put" the foreign keys, Hibernate takes care of that. Hibernate puts it on the `Job` table. You understand correctly.